# Ignore in-use files when mass-deleting in Explorer

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, file-management

In Explorer, if I select a large number of files/folders and hit 'delete', it will delete until it encounters an in-use file.  It brings up an 'error' dialog and stops deleting altogether - forcing you to either find/close the program that has the file handle or select everything *but* that file and try again, hoping that some other file won't *also* be in use.

Is there a way to ignore in-use files (leave them there) and continue trying to delete everything else?

Answer (score 4):

[Teracopy](http://www.codesector.com/teracopy.php) is what I use, works like a charm.